# Trying to create a MenuBar using Java.swing, and created an object of JMenu(), but it wont let me add It to the frame and not sure why?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

```
public class Menu  {

    private JMenu borders;

    //constructor
    public Menu()
    {

        //crate object
        //this.menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //------create menu items----

        //menu item for borders
        borders = new JMenu("Border");

        // add border options
        borders.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_U);

        //add border options
        borders.add(new JMenuItem("Etched"));
        borders.add(new JMenuItem("Raised"));
        borders.add(new JMenuItem("Matte"));
        borders.add(new JMenuItem("Tilted"));
        borders.add(new JMenuItem("Compounded"));

        JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        quit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Q);

        borders.add(quit);

        //set Accelerator
        quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, Event.CTRL_MASK));

        //add action listener
        //@Override
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });


    }

}

public class DrawingFrame extends JFrame{
    protected CanvasEditor canvasEditor;
    protected DrawingCanvas drawingCanvas;
    private Menu menu;



    public DrawingFrame()
    {
        this.setTitle("Drawing Application");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawingCanvas = new DrawingCanvas();
        drawingCanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,700));
        this.add(drawingCanvas);

        JPanel toolBarPanel = getToolBarPanel();

        this.add(drawingCanvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.add(toolBarPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //create menu from class
        this.menu = new Menu();

        //create menu bar
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //add menu to menuBar
        menuBar.add(menu);
```

---

```
error: cannot resolve method 'add'
```

not sure why it won't accept the `add` method

The `drawingFrame` class accepts objects from `canvasEditor` and `DrawingCanvas` but it doesn't accept objects from `Menu` class.

I want to create a `menuBar` and add a menu to it, and then have it on the same frame -- drawing Frame

pretty sure it's a simple fix, but not sure how to fix it

Comment: Please post the complete error message. You have several `add` methods and it's not clear which one the error you mention is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Menu  {
    private JMenu borders;
```

You create a class called `Menu` and create an instance of a `JMenu` in this class.

```
    this.menu = new Menu();

    //create menu bar
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //add menu to menuBar
    menuBar.add(menu);
```

You then create an instance of the `Menu` class and attempt to add it to the JMenuBar, which can't be done because the `Menu` class is NOT a `Component`.

Instead you want to add the `borders` variable to the menubar.

This means you need to create a method in your `Menu` class like:

```
public JMenu getJMenu()
{
    return borders;
}
```

Then you use:

```
//menuBar.add(menu);
menuBar.add( menu.getJMenu() );
```

Comment: So, the error was gone, but it still isn't showing up on the GUI app frame. Do you know how to set it up so it shows up on the frame?

Comment: Did you add the menu bar to the frame using the `setJMenuBar(...)` method? Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menu Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I figured it out!